How to figure out version of gcc in debian 8 or 9 distribution without installation?
I need to get gcc compiler version 4.9.0 exactly for its standard library to use with specific version of intel compilers.
I figured out debian 8 has almost the desired version of gcc. I made a virtual machine to only find out that gcc version in debian 8.11 is 4.9.2.
So my question is how I can precisely check gcc version inside the distribution (iso) without installing it?
Or maybe there is an easier solution to install specific gcc version?

A general way is to check distrowatch: https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=debian. Gcc is one of the main packages in the table of releases and package versions. While distrowatch is not authoritative in such matters, it is a reality-check because they do the legwork of checking those for you, or at least parsing release notes.
About debian/ubuntu family in particular, they tend to have multiple gcc versions available within a release. They would be named "gcc-11", "gcc-12", and "gcc-13".
And you're in luck for Debian. http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/gcc/. This site helps indicate which package versions were available when in Debian. You might need to calculate on your own which release of Debian that would have been, and then find that iso, but then download this deb, or point apt to that snapshot.debian.org url and fetch the exact version of gcc you want.

In addition to packaging resources like https://repology.org (where upstream maintainers actually do the footwork of registering the package names for software, and repology then goes ahead and checks the versions available; understandably, considering there's 3152 known packagings of gcc in active distors, it doesn't track end-of-life distros like debian 8 and 9), there's of course to set up a full VM. Just a container would totally suffice:
podman run -it --rm debian:8

(use docker if you prefer that over podman).

Or maybe there is an easier solution to install specific gcc version?

If building gcc and installing it into a prefix feels like too much work, maybe just build the gcc package for your current distro using the right version of the source code?
But the container way does generally sound like the way to go here: your ICC will not be built for your modern Linux distro anyways. You can just mount a directory containing the source code you want to work with as volume in your containers, at no overhead, and just run your builds inside. Containers is how most CI works these days, so it's the standard way of getting some specific environment including a specific compiler version around.
